# Concat dataframes on different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 different csv files and I'm looking for concat the values. The only condition I need is that the first csv dataframe must be in column A of the new csv, the second csv dataframe in the column B and the Thirth csv dataframe in the C Column. The quantity of rows is the same for all csv files.
Also I need to change the three headers to `['año_pasado','mes_pasado','este_mes']`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('año_pasado_subastas2.csv', sep=',')

df1 = pd.read_csv('mes_pasado_subastas2.csv', sep=',')

df2 = pd.read_csv('este_mes_subastas2.csv', sep=',')

df1
>>>
Subastas
166665859
237944547
260106086
276599496
251813654
223790056
179340698
177500866
239884764
234813107

df2
>>>
Subastas
212003586
161813617
172179313
209185016
203804433
198207783
179410798
156375658
130228140
124964988

df3
>>>
Subastas
142552750
227514418
222635042
216263925
196209965
140984000
139712089
215588302
229478041
222211457
```

The output that I need is:

```
año_pasado,mes_pasado,este_mes
166665859,124964988,142552750
237944547,161813617,227514418
260106086,172179313,222635042
276599496,209185016,216263925
251813654,203804433,196209965
223790056,198207783,140984000
179340698,179410798,139712089
177500866,156375658,215588302
239884764,130228140,229478041
234813107,124964988,222211457
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of `Series` created by `squeeze=True` if one column data only or selecting columns and for new columns names use parameter `keys`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('año_pasado_subastas2.csv', squeeze=True)
df1 = pd.read_csv('mes_pasado_subastas2.csv', squeeze=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('este_mes_subastas2.csv', squeeze=True)

cols = ['año_pasado','mes_pasado','este_mes']
df = pd.concat([df, df1, df2], keys = cols, axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv('año_pasado_subastas2.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('mes_pasado_subastas2.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('este_mes_subastas2.csv')

cols = ['año_pasado','mes_pasado','este_mes']
df = pd.concat([df['Subastas'], df1['Subastas'], df2['Subastas']], keys = cols, axis=1)

print (df)
   año_pasado  mes_pasado   este_mes
0   166665859   212003586  142552750
1   237944547   161813617  227514418
2   260106086   172179313  222635042
3   276599496   209185016  216263925
4   251813654   203804433  196209965
5   223790056   198207783  140984000
6   179340698   179410798  139712089
7   177500866   156375658  215588302
8   239884764   130228140  229478041
9   234813107   124964988  222211457
```